# Django date time filter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a createdAt field in my database which stores the current time stamp.And when I render it to my templates it returns in the form of `Aug. 24, 2017, 12:58 p.m.`.
What I want it to return in the form of `Aug. 24, 2017, 12:58 PM`.That is am/pm should be in caps form.
what I tried in my templates are:-

```
<td>{{ item.newsId.createdAt|time:"g:iA" }}</td>
```

and what it returned is only time `10:27AM`.But I want the date also along with this time format.

Comment: can you check timezone

Comment: it's a question of time representation of time what it has to do with timezone...just asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>{{ item.newsId.createdAt|date:"M. d,Y, f A" }}</td>
```

check below ss
[image]

Hi can you try above one

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like below

```
<td>{{ item.newsId.createdAt|date:"N j, Y, g:iA" }}</td>
```

for more configurations visit [django builtins date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: thanks, @satendra yours also works fine but unfortunately can accept only one answer but giving u upvote for that

Answer (score 0):

This helps to see the date time in this format: `1 day, 8 hours` suitable to add 1 day, 8 hours ago ;)
`<td>{{ item.newsId.createdAt|timesince }}</td>`